# Dare to guess what I am?

Tags: riddle

I have many colors

I'm a transformation of another thing

I can be different things, if shaped properly

I can hurt you

I used to be strong, but now I'm thin and fragile

I usually don't come alone

I'm here for a really long time

I can be of use alone or with other things

There is no age limit to use me

I come with a price, but I was born free.

What am I?

EDIT 1: Here is another line to help you figure out the answer, if you need:

> If I die correctly, I can become me again

Comment: memories was my guess until the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be

> Paper

I have many colors

> Paper though often white can have many other colours

I'm a transformation of another thing

> Commonly made from wood pulp

I can be different things, if shaped properly

> Can be e.g. notepaper or rolls of wrapping pepper

I can hurt you

> Paper cut

I used to be strong, but now I'm thin and fragile

> Used to be a tree and now a sheet of paper

I usually don't come alone

> Often in pages of a book

I'm here for a really long time

> Paper last for centuries

I can be of use alone or with other things

> Paper aeroplanes or with pens for writing paper

There is no age limit to use me

> From babies using tissue to centenarians writing

I come with a price, but I was born free.

> Paper costs but comes from trees

EDIT 1:

> If I die correctly, I can become me again
>
>  Paper if recycled can become itself again

Comment: Correct! Verry nice!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> ICE

Explanation follows

I have many colors

> Colored Ices (Ice sticks) and Ice Creams.

I'm a transformation of another thing

> Transformation of water

I can be different things, if shaped properly

> Ice cubes, Blocks, Ice creams, Ice Sticks, Sip-up etc

I can hurt you

> Can cause toothache and freezes if hold in hand for long.

I used to be strong, but now I'm thin and fragile

> Ice blocks are strong, but Ice sticks are fragile

I usually don't come alone

> With a stick. or may be some time with drinks.

I'm here for a really long time

> Reference to natural ice or may be the ice age.

I can be of use alone or with other things

> Icesticks can be used alone. Ice can be used alone if injured. Ice can be used with drinks or other consumable items.

There is no age limit to use me

> Definitely no age limit

I come with a price, but I was born free.

> If bought from store, we have to pay. But ice is made by freezing (when the temperature goes down) which is free.

If I die correctly, I can become me again

> If ice melt to water, it can be frozen back to ice again.

What am I?

> Ice / Ice stick

Comment: I would say maybe Glacier/Iceberg to fit it more.

Comment: wrong awnser, better luck next time!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Glass

I have many colors

> Glass can be of many colors.

I'm a transformation of another thing

> Transformation of sand.

I can be different things, if shaped properly

> IVases of different shapes, windows, cups etc.

I can hurt you

> Glass can cut you and cause serious injuries..

I used to be strong, but now I'm thin and fragile

> Glass is made of sand. Sand is strong, you can't really damage it.

I usually don't come alone

> In a phone, a tablet, a TV, windows...

I'm here for a really long time

> Glass is one of the Earth's oldest human-made materials.

I can be of use alone or with other things

> Glass can be used in windows(alone), or phones, computers etc.(with other things)

There is no age limit to use me

> People of all ages use glass somehow, glass is everywhere. TVs, tablets, phones, computers, cups, windows.

I come with a price, but I was born free.

> You can buy glass, either alone or in something like a phone. But glass is made of sand, which you can get for free.

If I die correctly, I can become me again

> Glass can be crushed back into sand.

Comment: nope, incorrect, but nice try

Comment: I was thinking in the same answer